# android Unfortunately Application has stopped working with string array using listadapter

Tags: android

i want to know why application crashes when i use this.
i have used it with another application and that working fine but in this application its not working properly.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Calculator", "Unit Converter" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, Rig.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;
    }
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Toast.makeText(this, item + " Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

this is main activity which works fine if i change the Menu.class to any other activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent newactivity = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(newactivity);
    finish();
}
```

manifest file code added

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.blogspot.andriopak.rig.Menu"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blogspot.andriopak.menu" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: `i want to know why application crashes` then read the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every activity you start with `startActivity` needs to be in the manifest. If that is your complete manifest then it is missing the definition for the `Rig` activity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Rig class implementation? Your code looks fine.

Is Menu your main activity? Is Menu activity started right if not main activity?

Edit 1: Can you please attach Rig.java, it is possible that you are getting some runtime exception in it, there is no other reason for this code to fail. You can test it without starting new activity in onListItemClick.

Edit 2: That means your activity can be launched with intent that has "com.blogspot.andriopak.menu" action:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.blogspot.andriopak.menu");
startActivity(intent);
```

Rig.java class is either undefined in AndroidManifest or it is throwing some kind of exception.

You should also check android debugging with [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#using-ddms), it is the easiest way to  pinpoint errors like this one, usefull and powerful tool anyway.

Comment: i have added main activity at the end of my question

Comment: my code is fine please suggest what should i do with manifest file i have added the code in manifest which is at the end of my question